# Como exibir uma imagem na tela

Tags: java, android

Estou com uma duvida de exibir uma imagem na tela em android.
exemplo.
para chamar um som utiliza o seguinte código:

```
Button button1;
MediaPlyer mp;
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Teste.this, R.raw.som);
        mp.start();

        }

    });
```

e como faz para chamar uma imagem?

Comment: Qual é a imagem? Onde está ela?

Comment: estou fazendo um código onde você clica na imagem e ela cresce, tomando a tela do dispositivo e quando clica de novo ela diminui.

Comment: Terminei, Rodolfo, você quer?

Comment: Onde ficarão essas imagens? Em uma pasta do app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No *Layou*t da sua *Activity* tem de declarar uma `ImageView`

Se quiser que ela seja apenas visível após carregar num botão deverá incluir o atributo `android:visibility="invisible"`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/nomeDaSuaImagem" />
```

No código da *Activity*, no `onClick` do botão, torne-a visível:

```
Button button1;
ImageView imageView1;

imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE;
    }

});
```

Comment: valeu ramaral vou experimenta logo comento.

Comment: ramaral tem como deixar imageView atras dos botoes e quando ela abrir pegar a tela inteira?

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e poste o ***xml*** da sua *Activity*

Answer (score 4):

Se você quiser abrir a imagem no visualizador padrão de imagens, pode fazer:

```
public void openInGallery(String imageId) {
   Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(imageId).build();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Você também pode tentar:

```
public void openImage(String imagePath) {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath), "image/*");
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15421803/1608936)

[`EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) é usado para especificar um local externo, se a imagem estiver num local interno use [`INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).

Comment: Você sabe a maneira correta de chamar o caminho da imagem?

Answer (score 2):

A sua pergunta foi tanto quanto complexa e ao mesmo tempo que sem metas para o objetivo:imagem na tela no android. Bem...Vamos sair das críticas e partir para minha resposta.

`Suposição e lógica`:

**Imaginando** que você queira que o cliente baixe uma determinada imagem, ao iniciar o app, e, que ela fique salva dentro da pasta imagens do seu próprio dispositivo. Para que isso? Não sei...Novidades sobre alguma coisa? Então seria necessário baixar a imagem de uma `url externa` e converte-la para `bitmap` e assim exibir em uma `ImageView` E TAMBÉM, ao clicar nela, seria bom criar uma espécie de `lightbox` para que não ocupe tanto espaço na tela do dispositivo com um tamanho fixo, setado. Com tudo isso, seria fácil atualizar todos os clientes, com uma imagem só, vindo de um servidor externo, pois você poderia altera-la quando quisesse, ao contrário seria se estivesse dentro de `drawble`.

**1.MainActivity.class**

```
package app.test;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    //ISTO DETERMINA O TAMANHO DA IMAGEM DEPOIS DO TOQUE
    private float mScaleFactor = 6f;

    private float globalX;
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();    
    private float mFocusX = 0.f;
    private float mFocusY = 0.f;  
    private int mImageHeight = 0;
    private Uri caminho;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Isto esconde o erro na hora de baixar o bitmap para as versões mais atuais do SDK
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


       //Criando a novos diretórios somente INSTALAR O APP
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                     File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"/MeuApp/Imagens/");
                        directory.mkdirs();

                }

       //Obtendo DisplayMetrics do dispositivo: largura e altura.
       DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
       int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
       int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        //Altere o valor atual: 10f, para um valor que desejar. Isto posicionará a imagem
        mFocusX = width/10f;
        mFocusY = height/10f;       

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

        //**2 passos para baixar a imagem, por isso os códigos devem está nessa ordem

        // 1 - Toda vez que o app for iniciado, ele ira baixar a imagem. Esta linha de código pode está onde desejar
        imageLoader.baixando(); 

        // 2 - Caminho da imagem baixada
        caminho = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/MeuApp/Imagens/" + "imagem" );

        view.setImageURI(caminho);  

        // Setando esta classe em touchListener para a ImageView
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //Se a posição 'x', no plano cartesiano, for menor que 102.4
        if (globalX < 102.4){

            //Setando uma nova escala para x e y, no plano 
            float scaledImageCenterX = (mImageHeight*mScaleFactor)/2;
            float scaledImageCenterY = (mImageHeight*mScaleFactor)/2;       

            //Mudando escala
            mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            //Mudando a transação
            mMatrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaledImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaledImageCenterY);

            //Setando as novas configurações da ImageView
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            view.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);           

            //Salvando valor da posição x na variável globalX através do Matrix
            float[] values = new float[9];
            mMatrix.getValues(values);
            globalX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

            return false; 

        }else{  

             // AQUI ACONTECE A REVERSÃO DO TAMANHO ATRAVÉS DA FUNÇÃO reset();
             mMatrix.reset();

             //Setando as novas configurações da ImageView
             ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
             view.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);

             // zerando a posição x para a condicional ser refeita
             globalX = 0; 


        }
        return false;


    }   


}
```

**2.ImageLoader.class**

```
package app.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;


public class ImageLoader {

    //Conexão, baixando e convertendo

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            URL src = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) src.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    //Salvando o Bitmap na pasta do app
    public void salvando(Bitmap abmp){      
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/MeuApp/Imagens/";
                File dir = new File(file_path);
                if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(dir, "imagem");
                FileOutputStream fOut;
                try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ;
                abmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }


    }

    //Executando os métodos: salvando e getBitmapFromURL
    public void baixando() {

        salvando(getBitmapFromURL("http://www.meusite.net/imagens/MATENHAesteTITULO.jpg"));

        return;
    } 

}
```

**3.activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toque na Imagem" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Não esquecer de adicionar isto no **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**DÚVIDAS? Deixe um comentário!**

Comment: @Rodolfo, ainda tem problemas?

Comment: Tipo, eu toco, a imagem cresce e toco de novo e imagem cresce mais um pouco e na terceira vez ela fica normal?

Comment: Você mexeu. Agora tem que reconfigurar.

Comment: Presta atenção: A sua imagem já vem grande, ela vem do tamanho que está na pasta da url externa ok? Quando você toca, ela diminui, pois a configuração atual, manda ela para uma escala menor que a atual(tamanho). Você conseguiu entender? Você tem que decidir o tamanha que irá ser sua imagem, NO SERVIDOR EXTERNO, depois mude as configurações no código. Me manda a `salvando(getBitmapFromURL("...");`